# Using AWS Cognito to keep a user in ios logged in

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have used AWS Lambda and amazon cogntio to authenticate users.

I used:

```
getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
```

and get a identity and token. Do I need to save bought locally in my app to keep a user logged in? How do I keep the user permanently logged in? Does the identity expire like the token? Can I get a new token without having the user login again?

I want to access various amazon services with the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

The identity id itself does not expire. If you pass the same key value pair `"developer_provider_name": "developer_user_identifier"` with *getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity*, the service returns the same identity id.

The token expires in duration which was given to the service in the [TokenDuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html#CognitoIdentity-GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity-request-TokenDuration) parameter, by default 15 minutes. All you need to call the service again is `developer_user_identifier` and the user does not need to login again necessarily.